# Logging out after switching tty

Tags: 16.04, tty, logout

I'm on ubuntu 16.04
after switching from another tty back to tty7 i sometimes get logged out and have to relogin.
Same as when i would use killall -u [myusername].
Problem is that i dont use any kill command or anything else.

Comment: Auto logout maybe?

Comment: Anything in `/var/crash/` when this happens?

Comment: @jdwolf
only after 1 hour, i happens after a shorter time

Comment: @dobey i have to files in there: 
"_usr_lib_unity-settings-daemon_unity-settings-daemon.1000.crash"
and
"_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash"

Comment: OK, so it looks like a bug that caused a crash. You should upload the crash reports.

Comment: @dobey where do i do this?

Comment: There should have been a dialog popped up when you rebooted and logged in, asking to report the crashes.